# Create Facebook-like Sitemap as shown on Google search results

Tags: sitemap

How do you create a sitemap for ASP.NET MVC website which can appear on any search engine like the facebook search results on Google search?

[image: facebook search result on google]

I have already created an xml sitemap which I submitted to Google but when I search for my site it only shows basic results.

Comment: Hi Mitch, since you closed my question as off the topic, what Q&A site would you recommend as I find the question related to a web developer/administrators role?

Comment: +1 I had the same question and alexn und you helped me! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These links are called site links. You cannot "create" them per se, Google decides when and which links to show. However, you can help Google determine which links are the most relevant.

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to
>   the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms
>   to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your
>   site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

Read about [sitelinks](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334) on Google Webmster Tools.